# Cannot add configurable products to cart when Product View blocks rendered outside of Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to display parts of the "Product View" page outside Magento. I'm able to get everything to show up properly and all the Javascript to load -- however, whenever I click the Add To Cart button, I'm given a message saying "Please specify the product's option(s)".

<strike>As noted in my comments, if I change</strike>

```
$addtocartBlock->createBlock()
```

to

```
$addtocartBlock->getBlockSingleton()
```

the entire top portion is replaced by the Add To Cart block. See edit.

Any thoughts?

I get the feeling that the **Add to Cart button** isn't working properly because it's not explicitly hooked up to the other blocks, though I might be wrong.

Alternatively, what would also be super helpful are some general guidelines in rendering these blocks programmatically -- while I'm fairly adept at PHP, Magento just loses me and I'm often just cutting and pasting [random snippets from the Magento forum](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/298924/).

Thank you!

---

### Edit:

After a bit more digging, a few more points:

1. Moving the renderView() calls below each block (instead of having them clumped together) fixes the "Add to cart replacing the main info block" issue.
2. Simple products are able to be added without issue. The only problem I'm having is making Magento recognize the product options submitted for configurable products.

### MOAR EDITZ!!!!!1111!

Further pursuant to this Question That Just Won't Die, I've discovered that @moldovan-gheorghe-daniel's correct about the "super_attribute" array not being sent with the rest of the POST. Further, if I use Firebug to cut and paste the configurable product fields as a child of the submitting `<form>` element, everything works beautifully. To finally cut to the chase:

## tl;dr -- HOW DO I LOAD THE CONFIGURABLE PRODUCT ATTRIBUTES BLOCK AS A CHILD OF THE ADD TO CART BLOCK?

*whew!*

Here's my code:

```
<?php
//Pretty standard loading Magento stuff.
$bootstrap = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/magento/app/Mage.php';
require_once $bootstrap;
session_name ( 'frontend' );
Mage::getSingleton ( 'core/session', array ('name' => 'frontend' ) );
$app = Mage::app('default');
$app->getTranslator()->init('frontend'); 
umask(0);
session_name('frontend');
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); //I'm not sure I need this.

$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$_product->load($product_id);
Mage::unregister('product');
Mage::register('product', $_product);

//The following loads the main Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View block.      
$linksBlock = $app->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton("catalog/product_view");
$linksBlock->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('catalog/product/view.phtml');

//The following loads the configurable product attributes block.
$checkoutLinksBlock = $app->getLayout()
                          ->getBlockSingleton("catalog/product_view_type_configurable")
                          ->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml');
$checkoutLinksBlock->setParentBlock($linksBlock);

/* The following loads the Add To Cart block. If I use getBlockSingleton() instead
 * of createBlock(), this replaces the entire top block. */

$addtocartBlock = $app->getLayout()
                      ->createBlock("catalog/product_view")
                      ->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml');
$addtocartBlock->setParentBlock($linksBlock);

$blocks['info'] = $linksBlock->renderView();
$blocks['addtocart'] = $addtocartBlock->renderview();
if ($_product->getTypeId() == 'configurable')
    $blocks['config'] = $checkoutLinksBlock->renderView();
else 
    $blocks['config'] = '';

Mage::unregister('product');

// ...And output everything here.
echo $blocks['info'] . $blocks['config'] . $blocks['addtocart'];
```

Comment: When you say you want to view parts of Magento outside of the store, what exactly is it you want to achieve? If you want to embed product data in an external page, you can create a custom CMS page and add product information to it

Comment: @James -- I'm writing software that bridges Magento with Drupal.

Comment: Have you had any success with http://drupal.org/project/magento?

Comment: @james -- There's no Drupal 7 version of that and it seems the maintainers are not supporting it anymore; see: http://drupal.org/node/1848762

Comment: Whilst this solution might work on a temporary basis, in the long run you are going to run into problems. What if the Magento codebase is observing layout events? What if the user wants to change the template? What if the session_name is PHPSESSID (and not frontend, or something different)?

Comment: @james -- And I will deal with those as I get them. Why would the session name be "PHPSESSID"? It seems like these are edge cases that aren't likely to come up in the very limited role I'll be using Magento (mainly due to delegating most content management tasks to an actual CMS). I'm willing to admit that I don't know, though.

Comment: the session name is variable, and I've seen both `PHPSESSID` and `frontend` on development and production domains; it allows more than one PHP session per browser, as you can differentiate on the cookie name.

Comment: But, like, wouldn't the session name only change if somebody sets it using `session_name()`? I can't find a config option. This site is managed by an agency -- unless one of us working here explicitly changes the session name, how is this anywhere near a realistic problem? I can see it changing (maybe) if there are multiple stores, but couldn't I just disable that behaviour by toggling the "Use SID on frontend" config option under Web->Session Validation Settings? All the weird session stuff I do in the above snippet is to prevent conflicts with Drupal's session handling, if that's not clear.

Comment: What if the client decides to add another app on the same domain, maybe SugarCRM? This can - and will - cause conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

All configurable products need to be added to cart with a specific option, for the simple ones you only need quantity and id. This is how should look array of request when a configurable product is added to cart.

```
Array(
    [uenc] => aHR0cdsfsdfdsfdssssssssssssss
    [product] => 4816
    [qty] => 2
    [related_product] =>
    [super_attribute] => Array(
            [352] => 1093
        )
)
```

"super_attribute" contains what option user selected. So i suggest to check if that data are in browser request. Maybe you post data without js validation made properly, and user not select anything from configurable options available, or maybe configurable options dropdown is not rendered at all.

Comment: I don't really have access to the code right now, but I think the "super_attribute" part of the request isn't being sent. That said, all the Javascript's there and the select box is being properly populated and everything.

Comment: Awarding bounty -- it doesn't explicitly answer my question, but at least it's somewhat helpful. Leaving question open in case somebody has a solid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find an approach better suited to your needs, but here is what I'd do:

**Create a custom controller in Magento**

Alan Storm has some great Magento tutorials, check out [this one](http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world) for controllers. Extend the default product controller. This is the controller you will visit form a Drupal installation (maybe called in an iframe?).

**Create a custom layout**

Start [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide) - you'll be able to get a feel for how layouts work. Take a look at how the product page is rendered (check the layout XML files, as well as the .phtml templates). I'd have a think about what happens when an item is added to a cart too.

With the two above, you should have a product page with working functionality, and the ability to customise the page layout and style to work with your current site. It's not a true bridge per se. If that is what you are after, take a look at Magento's API.

If you still want to use your existing solution, take a look at the layout documentation from Magento. In the .phtml for the product view page, you will see what HTML is generated - and what HTML you need to generate - to mimic the add to cart form.

**EDIT**
Not sure why the downvotes without comments (if my answer is not to your liking, let me know why and I'll improve it). Magento is a framework, and whilst the accepted solution might work, it is not the 'Magento' way: future developers (including onself) will likely have a difficult time maintaining the provided solution. The extra effort in learning how Magento works (and incorporating it) is worth the effort - after all, your client is paying you to fix their problem.

Comment: Interesting, but it doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: @aendrew, you couldn't get it working, and my answer gives you an approach to fix your problem. Did you read the design guide, or check out the templates? Did you look at the product view controller? The answer is all there.

Comment: So, your answer is essentially "RTFM", then?

Comment: @aendrew In a nutshell, yes. Magento is a framework on top of Zend, and cutting and pasting pieces of code makes development and debugging harder. By learning how it works, you'll be able to develop a simple solution that fixes your problem whilst learning the how and why. I assume you are being paid by a client for this work? If so, I can charge you for a fix to your current solution. If it's a hobby or a learning exercise, you will gain more knowledge by doing things to standard

Comment: You're suggesting using iframes. The whole point of what I'm doing -- whether "standard" or not -- is to *avoid* using iframes for both SEO and performance reasons. Again, my code *does* work, it's just that the configurable product select box isn't submitting with the rest of the form.

Comment: I initially downvoted it because I felt it was unhelpful (The added "...Now hire me!" doesn't do you any favours either), but given that I hate it when people downvote my stuff without comments, I decided that was too harsh. In the interest of "not being a jerk" (and because I have a lot of time this morning), I'm going to read through the documentation you linked to and try to figure out why exactly you're saying what I'm trying to do won't work.

Comment: I didn't say hire me: I haven't worked with Drupal commercially. I was more making the point that StackOverflow is a free community, and that I was giving advice from lessons learned. Magento is complicated and difficult to understand, sometimes 'RTFM' is the best way to learn the more complex components. True, it doesn't answer your exact question, but it gives you the tools you need to be able to answer it yourself.

Comment: I've probably read over 150 pages of Magento documentation today (Including the *entire* designer guide) and I am neither closer to a solution nor at all sure why you're being so unnecessarily smug. This will always be via the default handle, and while I acknowledge Magento allows a degree of variability such that it's hard to 100% anticipate all possible cases, this isn't supposed to a "one size fits all" solution. Do you even get what I'm trying to do? I don't want a "product view page", I want to pull arbitrary product details into Drupal  nodes.

Comment: Frankly, I'd have moved to using the RESTful API ages ago were it not for the fact I'm trying to reproduce elements as faithfully between the two systems as possible without having to re-template them all in Drupal --  but then again, were it up to me, I'd never have embarked upon this in the first place and just done everything in Ubercart.

Comment: @aendrew Smug? I'm taking time out of my day to point you in the right direction, with a starting point that you can build off to learn how Magento works, and how you can make it work for you. It's not easy, it can't be learnt in a day, but it is worthwhile to produce usable, maintainable code.